# I am trying to use pyautogui and its giving me this error

Tags: python, pyautogui

this is the code:

```
import pyautogui
btn = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Screenshot_1.png")
pyautogui.moveTo()
pyautogui.doubleClick()
```

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isGUj.png)

i already tried to reinsatll and it does'nt
work

Comment: But have you installed Pillow or PIL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You must install `pillow`. Use this command:**

```
pip install Pillow
```